# Displaying a large number of rows is slow despite the query being fast

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm facing an issue with a query that takes far too long (around 5 seconds). I've read a lot of pg performance post but they are confusing me somehow. So hopefully you can help me out!

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE
  SELECT e.uid AS employee_uid, loc.city, eco.company_name as company, et.tag, el.name as language, eq.qualification_type as qualification
  FROM employee e
  LEFT JOIN employee_tag et ON et.employee_uid = e.uid
  LEFT JOIN employee_qualification eq ON eq.employee_uid = e.uid
  LEFT JOIN employee_address ea ON ea.employee_uid = e.uid
  LEFT JOIN address a ON ea.address = a.id
  LEFT JOIN location loc ON loc.id = a.location
  LEFT JOIN employee_spoken_language el ON el.employee_uid = e.uid
  LEFT JOIN employee_company eco ON eco.employee_uid = e.uid
  WHERE 
    e.is_activated = True
    AND e.is_expired = False
    AND eco.company_name IN ('mycompany')
    AND (e.uid IN ('_null') OR True = True)
```

```
"Hash Right Join  (cost=175.88..368.89 rows=7267 width=105) (actual time=4.563..18.427 rows=47902 loops=1)"
"  Hash Cond: ((et.employee_uid)::text = (e.uid)::text)"
"  ->  Seq Scan on employee_tag et  (cost=0.00..94.49 rows=4149 width=71) (actual time=0.004..0.466 rows=4149 loops=1)"
"  ->  Hash  (cost=167.60..167.60 rows=663 width=91) (actual time=4.547..4.547 rows=2737 loops=1)"
"        Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 321kB"
"        ->  Hash Right Join  (cost=137.72..167.60 rows=663 width=91) (actual time=2.366..3.359 rows=2737 loops=1)"
"              Hash Cond: ((eq.employee_uid)::text = (e.uid)::text)"
"              ->  Seq Scan on employee_qualification eq  (cost=0.00..20.17 rows=817 width=64) (actual time=0.004..0.098 rows=817 loops=1)"
"              ->  Hash  (cost=133.87..133.87 rows=308 width=82) (actual time=2.354..2.354 rows=821 loops=1)"
"                    Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 89kB"
"                    ->  Hash Right Join  (cost=109.86..133.87 rows=308 width=82) (actual time=1.534..1.992 rows=821 loops=1)"
"                          Hash Cond: ((el.employee_uid)::text = (e.uid)::text)"
"                          ->  Seq Scan on employee_spoken_language el  (cost=0.00..17.95 rows=795 width=64) (actual time=0.003..0.078 rows=795 loops=1)"
"                          ->  Hash  (cost=108.03..108.03 rows=147 width=75) (actual time=1.519..1.519 rows=283 loops=1)"
"                                Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 29kB"
"                                ->  Hash Right Join  (cost=79.89..108.03 rows=147 width=75) (actual time=1.093..1.394 rows=283 loops=1)"
"                                      Hash Cond: (loc.id = a.location)"
"                                      ->  Seq Scan on location loc  (cost=0.00..22.11 rows=911 width=17) (actual time=0.003..0.105 rows=911 loops=1)"
"                                      ->  Hash  (cost=78.05..78.05 rows=147 width=74) (actual time=1.073..1.073 rows=283 loops=1)"
"                                            Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 30kB"
"                                            ->  Hash Right Join  (cost=67.53..78.05 rows=147 width=74) (actual time=0.695..0.863 rows=283 loops=1)"
"                                                  Hash Cond: (a.id = ea.address)"
"                                                  ->  Seq Scan on address a  (cost=0.00..7.40 rows=440 width=16) (actual time=0.004..0.042 rows=440 loops=1)"
"                                                  ->  Hash  (cost=65.69..65.69 rows=147 width=74) (actual time=0.684..0.684 rows=283 loops=1)"
"                                                        Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 30kB"
"                                                        ->  Hash Right Join  (cost=52.41..65.69 rows=147 width=74) (actual time=0.415..0.612 rows=283 loops=1)"
"                                                              Hash Cond: ((ea.employee_uid)::text = (e.uid)::text)"
"                                                              ->  Seq Scan on employee_address ea  (cost=0.00..10.23 rows=423 width=64) (actual time=0.004..0.041 rows=423 loops=1)"
"                                                              ->  Hash  (cost=50.76..50.76 rows=132 width=66) (actual time=0.398..0.398 rows=181 loops=1)"
"                                                                    Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 17kB"
"                                                                    ->  Hash Join  (cost=8.85..50.76 rows=132 width=66) (actual time=0.138..0.327 rows=181 loops=1)"
"                                                                          Hash Cond: ((e.uid)::text = (eco.employee_uid)::text)"
"                                                                          ->  Seq Scan on employee e  (cost=0.00..39.79 rows=213 width=61) (actual time=0.016..0.124 rows=195 loops=1)"
"                                                                                Filter: (is_activated AND (NOT is_expired))"
"                                                                                Rows Removed by Filter: 184"
"                                                                          ->  Hash  (cost=5.93..5.93 rows=234 width=62) (actual time=0.112..0.112 rows=234 loops=1)"
"                                                                                Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 22kB"
"                                                                                ->  Seq Scan on employee_company eco  (cost=0.00..5.93 rows=234 width=62) (actual time=0.007..0.054 rows=234 loops=1)"
"                                                                                      Filter: ((company_name)::text = 'mycompany'::text)"
"Planning time: 4.376 ms"
"Execution time: 19.929 ms"
```

And here's the explain result: [Explain Result](http://explain.depesz.com/s/qW54)

Comment: `"Execution time: 19.929 ms"` - the query itself only takes 20ms and returns 47902 rows. I guess it's your application that takes 5 seconds to _display_ the data. Or you have a slow network where sending the data is slow.

Comment: You show all an employee's combinations of cities, tags, qualifications, and languages. That doesn't seem to make much sense. Why would you want to Show that employee X has an address in New York and speaks English an Italian and has an address in Seattle, too, and speaks English an Italian. You are showing the same data again and again. You may want to make this separate queries instead.

Comment: Many outer joins. Are they all needed? Doesn't have each employee have at least one address? And doesn't an employee speak at least one language? On `employee_company` you are even applying an outer join but your WHERE clause renders it a mere inner join. (As `company_name` will be null in an outer-joined record, so it cannot match `AND eco.company_name IN ('mycompany')`. Put criteria on outer joins in ON, not in WHERE).

Comment: Thanks for all your comments. This query is used to show all possible "Directory filters" to limit the employees by criterias. E.g. all employees in New York, speaking French, having human-resource skills etc. So yes, the joins are required. Interesting is the 19ms, I thought those are seconds :-O! So this basically explains a lot!

Comment: There's at least a logic error: `eco.company_name IN ('mycompany')` turns the `LEFT JOIN employee_company` into an INNER Join. Hopefully the optimier is smart enough to recognize that, check if it's actually returning the result you want.